# Regex to match words with length ranges

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and I am having a hard time filtering out words with the length range from 5-7. So here is an example

I have a wordlist, where the words are seperated by whitespace

```
house computer method position regex avocado
```

Now let's say I only want words with the length of 5, 6 and 7. 
The regular expression I am searching for would match anything else.

If I were to replace the matches with nothing I would expect this output.

```
house method regex avocado
```

Thanks. :)

E:

I am using this site: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Specify the regex engine or programming language you are using as per the tag excerpt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `{n,m}` quantifier, with word boundaries:

```
\b\w{5,7}\b
```

It will match a "word" of 5 to 7 alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @TimPietzcker. OOPs. Forgot word boundary.

Comment: you need word boundary, otherwise it will match `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` too

Comment: well I need the opposite of that. I need to match anything else :)

Comment: @Chrene. Well, you can use any of this answer or the other one. In one you replace, in other you select.

Comment: true :) The other answer was just the one I needed. Thanks anyways for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the regex:

```
\b(\w{1,4}|\w{8,})\b
```

And replace by nothing.

See how it works [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/kY6zX7)

After that, you can clean by removing any trailing and double spaces left behind.

Comment: @Chrene Haha, I'll set my alarm here ;) Time to sleep in my timezone.

Comment: Accepted thanks for the quick reply and good night to you sir :)

Comment: @chrs Did something happen?